# Is it possible to count the number of items in a Haskell list?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to count the number of items in a list in Haskell, but all i can find online is that you can do this only if you are using a value to satisfy the condition.

I was wondering if you can use a generic `count :: List -> Int` function which will give the number of elements in the list

Comment: Start using [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/); you can even use type signatures in your search. The first entry in the result of https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D+-%3E+Int is `length`, which does exactly what you want.

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:length

Comment: Of course you _should_ use `length` for this, but I wonder... whence did you get “you can do this only if you are using a value to satisfy the condition”? As a matter of fact, if you try to implement that function naïvely with recursion, you'll readily see that the actually elements aren't really needed, only the list constructors are.. `length' [] = 0`; `length' (_:l) = 1 + length' l`.

Comment: Thanks guys! That's answered my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`length :: [a] -> Int` is a function that returns the length of any list.

For example, `length [1, 1, 2, 42, 7]` evaluates to 5.